# Prove that the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is isomorphic to the group of positive rational numbers under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, group-isomorphism

The question (from my exam) quoted verbatim:

> Show that the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is isomorphic to the group of positive rational numbers under multiplication.

First of all, is this $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ the same as $\mathbb{Z}_x$ (addition modulo $x$)?

Secondly, how do I still get the isomorphism?

Thanks

Comment: $\Bbb Z[x]$ usually denotes the ring of univariate polynomial in the indeterminate $x$. Proceed by definition.

Comment: Wait we haven't been taught rings, can't it be done from ONLY group theory?

Comment: This is a choice of terminology. I could also just say that $\Bbb Z[x]$ is a **set** of univariate polynomials with integer coefficients, on which we could equip an addition operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Enumerate the set of prime natural numbers with nonnegative integers.  Say, $\{p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots\}$ is such an enumeration.  Prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^d\,k_n\,x^n\mapsto \prod_{n=0}^d\,p_n^{k_n}$$
is a group isomorphism from $\big(\mathbb{Z}[x],+\big)$ to $\big(\mathbb{Q}_{> 0},\cdot)$.

Comment: First please explain to me what "exactly" is the set Z[x]?

Comment: @PLAP_ Shouldn't have this been explained at some point in your course? It just means the set of polynomials with variable "x" with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring